# Exception thrown when using TaskSourceCompletion in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, .net-4.0, wcf-ria-services, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to wrap the Event Async Programming model used in RIA Services in a Task.

I have followed the standard way of using a TaskCompletionSource and implemented the following extension method:

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> LoadAsync<T>(this DomainContext source, EntityQuery<T> query) where T : Entity
{
    TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<T>> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<T>>();

    source.Load(
        query,
        loadOperation =>
        {
            if (loadOperation.HasError && !loadOperation.IsErrorHandled)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(loadOperation.Error);
                loadOperation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
            }
            else if (loadOperation.IsCanceled)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
            }
            else
            {
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(loadOperation.Entities);
            }
        },
        null);

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

I then use this in the following way:

```
var task = _context.LoadAsync(_context.GetPlayersQuery());
task.Start();
task.Result;
```

The problem though is that I get an InvalidOperationException stating that "Start may not be called on a promise-style task".  I have tried not starting the task, but then the loadOperation callback never fires.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't look like EAP: I don't see any events anywhere. What happens if you call `LoadAsync()` and don't wait for the result? Is the delegate called? If yes, is it called on the UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved.  Under the hood the DomainContext.Load() method is already operating in an asynchronous manner.  There must have been some conflict with trying to wrap an already asynchronous method in a task.

However, even if I still follow the EAP correctly with the code below, I still get the InvalidOperationException of 'start cannot be called on a promise-style task'

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> LoadAsync<T>(this DomainContext source, EntityQuery<T> query) where T : Entity
{
    TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<T>> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<T>>();

    var loadOperation = source.Load(query);
    loadOperation.Completed += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (loadOperation.HasError && !loadOperation.IsErrorHandled)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(loadOperation.Error);
            loadOperation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
        }
        else if (loadOperation.IsCanceled)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
        }
        else
        {
            taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(loadOperation.Entities);
        }
    };

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
var result = await _context.LoadAsync(_context.GetPlayersQuery());
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but there seems to be a bug with Silverlight and VS11 Beta where there are problems with using the 'async' keyword ([link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727285/vs11-beta-does-not-recognize-async-await-in-silverlight).  Seeing as this is just syntactic sugar on tasks, I was trying to achieve the same thing by using Task.Wait().

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`task.ContinuewWith(Action<Task<T>> continuation)`

That worked for me, as I too got that exception when using task.Start